# Why is there not a ZipInputStream that deflates?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream, outputstream

There is `java.io.ZipInputStream` that inflates and `java.io.ZipOutputStream`that deflates.

But sometimes I don't want that. Sometimes when using third parties APIs that accept an `InputStream`, I want a `ZipInputStream` that deflates.

Is there any reason I can't do this?

< /rant>

The real (constructive) question: is there a good way to get the equivalent of deflating `ZipInputStream` (not requiring multithread pipe streams)?

---

Yes, often one reads obtains a compressed stream from an uncompressed one.

But that can be done the other way around!

For example: read a File, ZIP compress it, and then upload it (as a stream) using the Apache HTTP client.

Comment: You could write one pretty easily.  How much coding are you willing to entertain?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, a hundred lines? I know nothing about ZIP archives or compression, so I don't know how difficult this is.

Comment: Plus, I feel like someone must have already done this...

Comment: Usually you read compressed data and get it uncompressed, not the other way around.  What are you doing with the compressed data?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess OP wants to pass compressed data to an API which accepts an InputStream.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, but this stream has to go somewhere which expects ZIPped data.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, the destination may accept any binary data.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, see edited question for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have both [DeflaterInputStream](http://itis0001.belluzzifioravanti.it/javadoc/java/util/zip/DeflaterInputStream.html) and [DeflaterOutputStream](http://itis0001.belluzzifioravanti.it/javadoc/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) however [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) is only for files inside a Zip file already. i.e. you can only use it in the context of having a ZIP file.

I suggest you try DeflatorInputStream which can be unzipped with InflaterInputStream or InflaterOutputStream.

Comment: But those are different than zip compression, yes?

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, Deflater is stand alone.  Zip is used for a file in a ZIP.  You can't use ZipInput/Output by itself.  You get it from inside a ZIP file.  BTW The use the same zlib library so they are very similar, just not exactly the same.

Comment: @PaulDraper I suspect this is not available as a ZIP file contains entries for one or more files. i.e. it is not as simple as wrapping a Stream. You have to call putNextEntry(ZipEntry) and closeEntry() at the start and end of each entry.  I believe it could be done, but it is more complicated than Deflater*Stream or Gzip*Stream.

Comment: That's a good point. You'd need to have a class or iterable or something that puts out `InputStream`s for each entry. Definitely a little more complicated than DeflaterStream.